# Почему итоговый вызов метода next генератора, берет a = 9;

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, замыкания, область-видимости, генераторы

Есть код. По логике итог должен быть `a = 12; b = 24;`, но итог `a = 12; b = 18;`. Скорее всего это из-за того, что при вызове метода `next` в последний раз используется `a = 9`, но в отладке непосредственно перед самим вызовом `next`, `a` уже равна `12` в глобальной области видимости. Помогите...

```js
function step(gen) {
  var it = gen();
  var last;

  return function() {
    last = it.next(last).value;
  };
}

function* foo() {
  a++;
  yield;
  b = b * a;
  a = (yield b) + 3;
}

function* bar() {
  b--;
  yield;
  a = (yield 8) + b;
  b = a * (yield 2);
}

let a = 1;
let b = 2;
let s1 = step(foo);
let s2 = step(bar);

s2();console.log(a, b); // b--;
s2();console.log(a, b); // yield 8
s1();console.log(a, b); // a++;
s2();console.log(a, b); // a = 8 + b; // 9
// yield 2
s1();console.log(a, b); // b = b * a;
// yield b
s1();console.log(a, b); // a = b + 3;
s2();console.log(a, b); // b = a * 2; но а равна 12, а не 9
```